# How to label areas in pgfplots fillbetween library

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there any simple way put a label say `$A$` roughly at the "center" of an area created by the pgfplots fillbetween library?

Take for example the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:5]
\addplot[name path=A] gnuplot {sin(x)};%
\addplot[name path=B] gnuplot {cos(x)};%
\addplot[opacity=0.5] fill between[of=A and B,
split,
every segment no 0/.style={yellow},
every segment no 1/.style={red},
every segment no 2/.style={green},
];

%% Choosing the coordinates manually is annoying:
\node at (axis cs:2,0.3) {$A_2$};
\node at (axis cs:0.2,0.5) {$A_1$};
\node at (axis cs:4.5,-0.6) {$A_1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Could you provide an MWE to save us the typing/setup?

Comment: Just added a MWE.

Comment: So what should be the deciding factor to place them within the area?

Comment: @percusse It should be visually in the "center" of the area. But it is not clear to me  how to define this in a more rigerous way.

Comment: Related, using closedcycle instead of fillbetween: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127591/labeling-the-center-of-a-closedcycle-area

Answer (score 3):

I suppose using barycentric coordinates could be an option, though some work is needed. In this case I add coordinates at the start and end of each plotline, and I name the intersections. The nodes aren't really placed in the middle of the area, but at the center of the coordinates used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:5]
\addplot[name path=A] gnuplot {sin(x)} coordinate[pos=0] (As) coordinate [pos=1] (Ae);
\addplot[name path=B] gnuplot {cos(x)} coordinate[pos=0] (Bs) coordinate [pos=1] (Be);
\addplot[opacity=0.5] fill between[of=A and B,
split,
every segment no 0/.style={yellow},
every segment no 1/.style={red},
every segment no 2/.style={green},
];

\path [name intersections={of=A and B,name=i}];

\node at (barycentric cs:As=1,Bs=1,i-1=1) {$A_1$};
\node at (barycentric cs:i-1=1,i-2=1) {$A_2$};
\node at (barycentric cs:i-2=1,Ae=1,Be=1) {$A_1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```